# Logging from Vendor classes in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have a CakePHP application that uses a number of vendor classes, including one to handle email.  We're having some issues with emails not arriving, so we want to add a log message every time an email gets sent.  The obvious place to do that is in the send function of the email class, but $this->log doesn't work, since the vendor object isn't built on the CakePHP one.

Is there anyway to access the CakePHP logging system from a non-CakePHP class?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a hint at this on another site.  The solution is

```
Debugger::log()
```

Some further details, since I ran in to a problem while doing this.  Your debug level needs to be greater than zero or you get a white screen.

Comment: upvoted for finding your own solution, then coming back to answer your own question.  Nice work!